# How to read endpoint configuration from another app.config file

Tags: wcf, configurationmanager, wcf-endpoint

I need to use a ServiceReference object in an plugin I’m writing.  However, this plugin has its own app.config file separate from the parent program’s config file.  I know how to access this secondary config file, but I still don’t know how to use that data in the constructor for my ServiceReference object.  The constructors for the object ask for string variables such as endpointConfigurationName or remoteAddress, but then my program can’t find the matching endpointConfigurationName in my secondary config file.  How do I force the program to use my secondary “myConfiguration” Configuration object?

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModel = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(myConfiguration);
myClient = new MyClient();
```

Comment: It sounds like you probably just want to open the other app.config as an ordinary XML file, and parse out the item you want.

Comment: How do I manually define a WebHttpBinding in C# code?

Comment: Q: How do I manually define a WebHttpBinding in C# code?  A: Usually,  you don't.  But you *can* create an instance of the web service subclass the IDE gives you, and dynamically change it's service address property.

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4.  Please add an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I appreciate the offer.  And I've definitely glad you resolved the problem.  SUGGESTION: Please accept your own answer.  It's already better than anything I would have replied, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @paulsm4 suggestion and found [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx) on Microsoft's site.  Using that, I ended-up with this, and it's working great:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyService> myFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new WebHttpBinding(), myRemoteAddress);
myFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
myClient = cf.CreateChannel();
```

I realize this doesn't exactly solve the original question, but I don't think there's a way to read ALL of the binding info from an alternate config file.  If there is, I welcome someone to answer the original question.